# jquery toggle show/hide issue

Tags: jquery

Hello I have applied jquery show/hide function in my website
but the problem is its first showing the text on loading the page and when page loads completely it then functions as normal
Please help
check my site
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/

Comment: You are inserting jquery-min.js, toggle.js and toggle1.css multiple times. Also do what @balexandre says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just hide the text in the first place using a CSS selector, in you exemple, this does the trick:

```
.storycontent { display: none; }
```

witch you can simply add `display: none;` to your `style.css` *(line 228)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer
when I am adding this it removed the jquery
this is my style.css for jquery

Comment: I want to display that story content in jquery
so If I add display: none; in style .css 
it will remove the story content which I wan to display
point is why its first showing it on page load and then dissapear and after that jquery works fine

Comment: jQuery `hide`, `show`, `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` used `display:none;` so if a selector has `display:none;`, when you use `.show()` it will remove that from that particular selector. For that the trick works just fine.

Comment: Also I want the image (plus-minus) to be located above (in other div) and show the requied toggle below at the same position

See this screen
http://i49.tinypic.com/xlihr7.jpg

Comment: don't get me wrong, but "I want" does not apply well in a community. Either you try for yourself to learn CSS, wither you show us that you are trying to do something and can't complete. We don't do homework! [You also should read our FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Ok I did it 
But one last thing
if you see at my jquery its a bit jerky that is when plus is clicked all the text below it move to right when comes down
see the jquery effect in this site
http://www.oxytheme.com/Interface/
whats the difference b/w the two
its the style or jquery itself?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to hide elements on a webside by css if they have to be hidden on startup, because the javascript needs some time to be activated (because it waits till the page is fully loaded).

I would use the same way as balexandre...